# Redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My main domain : `http://www.mydomain.com`

I have 3 directories in my domain:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/cms
http://www.mydomain.com/blog
http://www.mydomain.com/forum
```

I want that whenever someone types `www.mydomain.com` he must go to `http://www.mydomain.com/cms`
and later my other folders are anyways linked via menu items in my CMS, however the browser must show as `http://www.mydomain.com`only for the main page rest can be regular display.

I read some time back somewhere that it is possible to do so using the `.htaccess` file

Is it really possible to do this? If yes then how?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ cms
```